# How to improve hit rate to suggestions on picture identification questions?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions, exact-duplicates

I've tried editing the question [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/what-picture-is-this-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)
to try and get better hits on it by editing the title. However, it is most likely that doesn't really help. I was about to start dummy questions to link to the one above with more helpful titles such as "What picture is this from?" or "What anime is this from?" to ensure a better hit on the main reverse search question by acting as proxy.

We could also have some crazy long title with multiple combinations of the different questions but that would also reduce readability and make it less visible when actually searching that question.

I do not know if this is "kosher" and if we should do it, thus I post here instead.

Comment: If you want users that seek reverse image search to find our post about reverse image search, the most straightforward way would be to post a comment with a link to it. This is the only foolproof method that doesn't require additional posts or configuring help popups.

Comment: @Hakase I think Tyhja means for question prediction when asking a question (if I've read it correctly), rather than searching the site themselves

Comment: yes, I meant just that. That post won't appear coz the title length is very different.

Comment: Yes, both of you are right. And I've tried entering similar titles for questions and not getting hits for suggestions, which results in this meta post.